# resizing widget in pygtk

Tags: widget, size, pygtk

I have a scrolled window, which contains a drawing area in pygtk. I would like to change the size of the drawing area, and keep the scrolled window as it is. I don't find a function that works on widgets. I can get the size and so on, but I can't set it. Could someone give me a pointer to the solution?

Thanks,

v923z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like `.set_size_request()` is what you need. An example would be:

```
drawingarea.set_size_request(400, 400)
```

The values are the width and height of the canvas. Assuming you're ScrolledWindow is setup correctly, the scrollbars should adjust automatically to the size of the DrawingArea.